# How to color the lines and title in \chapterstyle{VZ43}

Tags: sectioning

I want to use the `\chaperstyle{VZ43}` in writing my book. How to color the vertical lines, section number box and chapter name in different colors?

Comment: And where is that style defined? Which document class do you use?

Comment: This chapter style is defined in memoir class

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Adjust the colors to your liking:

```
\documentclass{memoir}
\usepackage{calc,xcolor}

\definecolor{rulecolor}{RGB}{153,51,51}
\definecolor{chapternumcolor}{RGB}{228,154,74}
\colorlet{chaptertitlecolor}{magenta!60}
\colorlet{boxcolor}{green!80!black!40}

\newif\ifNoChapNumber
\newcommand\Vlines{%
\def\VL{\textcolor{rulecolor}{\rule[-2cm]{1pt}{5cm}}\hspace{1mm}\relax}
\VL\VL\VL\VL\VL\VL\VL}
\makeatletter
\setlength\midchapskip{0pt}
\makechapterstyle{VZ43}{
\renewcommand\chapternamenum{}
\renewcommand\printchaptername{}
\renewcommand\printchapternum{}
\renewcommand\chapnumfont{\Huge\bfseries\centering}
\renewcommand\chaptitlefont{\Huge\bfseries\raggedright}
\renewcommand\printchaptertitle[1]{%
\Vlines\hspace*{-2em}%
\begin{tabular}{@{}p{1cm} p{\textwidth-3cm}}%
\ifNoChapNumber\relax\else%
\colorbox{boxcolor}{\color{chapternumcolor}%
\makebox[.8cm]{\chapnumfont\strut \thechapter}}
\fi
& \chaptitlefont\textcolor{chaptertitlecolor}{##1}
\end{tabular}
\NoChapNumberfalse
}
\renewcommand\printchapternonum{\NoChapNumbertrue}
}
\makeatother
\chapterstyle{VZ43}

\begin{document}

\chapter{Test chapter}

\end{document}
```

If you want the style for the `book` class, you can use the original definition of the style by Vincent Zoonekynd which can be found [in this page](http://zoonek.free.fr/LaTeX/LaTeX_samples_chapter/0.html) and introduce the coloring commands:

```
\documentclass{book}
\usepackage{xcolor}

\definecolor{rulecolor}{RGB}{153,51,51}
\definecolor{chapternumcolor}{RGB}{228,154,74}
\colorlet{chaptertitlecolor}{magenta!60}
\colorlet{boxcolor}{green!80!black!40}

\makeatletter
\def\LigneVerticale{{\color{rulecolor}\vrule height 5cm depth 2cm}\hspace{0.1cm}\relax}
\def\LignesVerticales{%
  \let\LV\LigneVerticale\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV\LV}
\def\GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre#1{%
  \rlap{\textcolor{boxcolor}{\vrule height 0.8cm width 1cm depth 0.2cm}}%
  \rlap{\hbox to 1cm{\hss\mbox{\textcolor{chapternumcolor}{#1}}\hss}}%
  \vrule height 0pt width 1cm depth 0pt}

\def\@makechapterhead#1{\hbox{%
    \huge 
    \LignesVerticales
    \hspace{-0.5cm}%
    \GrosCarreAvecUnChiffre{\thechapter}
    \hspace{0.2cm}\hbox{\textcolor{chaptertitlecolor}{#1}}%
}\par\vskip 2cm}
\def\@makeschapterhead#1{\hbox{%
    \huge 
    \LignesVerticales
    %\hspace{0.5cm}%
    \hbox{\textcolor{chaptertitlecolor}{#1}}%
}\par\vskip 2cm}

\begin{document}
\chapter{A test chapter}
\end{document}
```

[image]

Comment: Instead of using \chapter{\textcolor{red}{Test chapter}} to color the chapter title, give suggestion to use   command in preamble.

Comment: @SGSekaran It's already in my answer. Use `\definecolor` or `\colorlet` to define `chaptertitlecolor`; in my example it is set to `magenta!60`, so you can say `\colorlet{chaptertitlecolor}{red}`.

Comment: Well, it is smoothly working in \documentclass{memoir}. If I use \documentclass{book}, so many errors are there. Let me know the changes to be done to use in \documentclass{book}

Comment: @SGSekaran Please see my updated answer.

Comment: Well. I am not good in using Latex.  I got the expected answer. It is working well. Thanks